# GET infos from HTTP website in CHROME with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, https

I'm trying to GET an url in Javascript who's only working in http.

It's from an external website, the HTTPS is not working, you only get an `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error and I cannot do anything about it

I tried to GET the Website in AJAX with the HTTP url like that

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://t.websitexxx/",
                type: "get",
                async: false
            });
```

With some datas,
But I get an `(blocked:mixed-content)` error

I tried to add the meta

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

But it only redirect my call in HTTPS, witch still give me the `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` error

How can I get this URL who's working only in HTTP in Google Chrome ?

Comment: You can’t, that’s the point ... `upgrade-insecure-requests` only means that the browser should try to make an HTTPS request for the HTTP address you have specified automatically by itself, but that doesn’t magically make a remote party, that answers to HTTP only, “speak” HTTPS all of a sudden. You will need to proxy this via a server that _does_ support HTTPS.